# Why is it null?

Tags: java, constructor

I understand that keyword "this" is used to call a constructor within another constructor. In the following code, I do not understand why NULL is used when calling the constructor as follows:

```
this(filename, null);
```

Here is the complete code:

```
class Image {
    Image(String filename) {
        this(filename, null);
        System.out.println("Image(String filename) called");
    }

    Image(String filename, String imageType) {
        System.out.println("Image(String filename, String imageType) called");
        if (filename != null) {
            System.out.println("reading " + filename);
            if (imageType != null) {
                System.out.println("interpreting " + filename + " as storing a " +
                        imageType + " image");
            }
        }
        // Perform other initialization here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the `imageType` is unknown.

Comment: If the solution solves your problem, you are encouraged to accept the solution (including all your past questions). A user who doesn't accept solutions turns me off.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!!!

Answer (score 0):

This was already alluded to in comments, but your first constructor does not know the image type, so it can't reasonably pass anything in other than `null`.  The second constructor is well-equipped to handle `null` for that parameter, so there's no risk of breakage resulting from that.

Comment: for calling another constructor , we need to pass all parameters, so  we don't parameter type in first constructor, so in order to calling second constructor , we have to pass `null` as second parameter, otherwise it will throw erros